# How display two div horizontally in my carousel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
/*slides show*/

var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
       slides[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    slideIndex++;
    if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "flex";  
    dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
    setTimeout(showSlides, 5000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}


/*End slides show*/
```

```css
img {vertical-align: middle;}

/* Slideshow container */

    .mySlides{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        width: 75vw;
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
    .mySlides > div {
        flex: 0 0 50%;
        border: 1px solid green;
    }


.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 50px;

}


/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
      box-sizing: border-box;


}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;

}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  height: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .text {font-size: 11px}
}
```

```html
<body>
     <div id="header" class="navbar">
  <div id="Title">
    <a href="Accueil"><img src="IMAGES/PNG/logo.png" alt="logo" /></a>
  </div>
  <div id="navbar">
    <div class="menu"> <a class="active" href="javascript:void(0)">Blog</a></div>
    <div class="menu"> <a href="blog">Contact</a></div>
    <div class="menu"> <a href="blog">L'électrophotonique</a></div>
    <div class="menu"> <a href="blog">Qui sommes nous?</a></div>
  </div>
</div>


  <div class="slideshow-container">

  <div id = "slideshow" class="mySlides fade">
    <div><img src="IMAGES/PNG/background.png"></div>
     <div class="text"> test1 </div>
   </div>


  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="IMAGES/PNG/eau59h.png">
    <div class="text">test 2</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="IMAGES/PNG/pont.png">
    <div class="text">test 3</div>
  </div>

  </div>
  <br>

  <div style="text-align:center">
    <span class="dot"></span> 
    <span class="dot"></span> 
    <span class="dot"></span> 
  </div>




  <div class="content" >



<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/sticky_navbar.js"></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script  src="js/index.js"></script>
```

I'm trying to display 2 divs in 1 row in my slide show ? 
One part is an image and the second is the legend and text.

I'm trying to use flexbox to do it but it doesn't work and I don't understand why.

I introduce a div with an ID (slideshow) for test but the div with the image and the the div class = "text" are still align vertically

Can you help me?

```js
/*slides show*/

var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
       slides[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    slideIndex++;
    if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
    dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
    setTimeout(showSlides, 5000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}


/*End slides show*/
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 28px;
  background-color: #00011f;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin : auto;
}


img {vertical-align: middle;}

/* Slideshow container */

#slideshow{
float: flex;}


.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 50px;

}


/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  height: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

/* On smaller screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .text {font-size: 11px}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/style2.css" />
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="IMAGES/PNG/favicon.png" />

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Electrophotonique Ingenierie</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


    </head>


    <body>
     
  <div class="slideshow-container">

  <div id = "slideshow" class="mySlides fade">
    <div><img src="IMAGES/PNG/background.png"></div>
    <div class="text"> testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest </div>
   </div>


  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="IMAGES/PNG/eau59h.png" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="IMAGES/PNG/pont.png" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text"></div>
  </div>

  </div>
  <br>

  <div style="text-align:center">
    <span class="dot"></span> 
    <span class="dot"></span> 
    <span class="dot"></span> 
  </div>


  <div class="content" ></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/sticky_navbar.js"></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script  src="js/index.js"></script>






</body>
</html>
```

[image: with the code edited]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added a Codepen which solves your problem, where you can inspect the changes I've made to your markup.

Flexbox is a display layout method, so I've replaced `float:flex` with `display:flex`. I've then added some further style rules, which result in a 2 column layout, each column being 50% of the flexbox container's width (as a width must be defined for this to work, I've set the width to 75vw, which equates to 75% of the browser screen width).

The markup for each 'slide' needs to be the same in order for the layout to work, so I've changed the style rule `#slideshow` to `.mySlides` and ensured that the image sits within a div tag, which I saw you had added to the first slide.

Here is the styling required (with some border colours set so you can see what is going on):

```
.mySlides{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 75vw;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.mySlides > div {
    flex: 0 0 50%;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

`flex: 0 0 50%` is a shorthand, but in this case instructs each column to occupy a minimum of 50% width.

I've made some other minor amends, but these are mostly cosmetic.

I hope this is useful. Questions are welcome :-)

[View Codepen](https://codepen.io/sassquad/pen/yxKMgN)

Comment: I change everything your said but they are still vertical... See the jpg in the post edit...

Comment: I did leave out an important point - the line `slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";` in your JS, this needs to be changed from `block` to `flex`. 

Ensure the img tags for the slides are sitting inside div tags, otherwise the styling won't work.

As I cannot see your live example, I will have to assume that there is some change I've made in my pen that is not present in yours. If you can update your post with the corrected markup, we can then see what's going on.

Comment: I edited the post. When I run with my code on the simulator it works... But not on my website :'(

Comment: ok I found my mistake... I didn't edited the good js file... thanks for your help !!

Answer (score 1):

the issue with your code was wrong property - `float: flex`, it should be `display: flex`, and you can' t set that to `#slideshow` as javascript update will change that to `display: block`.